# Get a word between

Tags: python, string

Say I have string like this :

> He said "I am his father."
>
> That pretty lady said "Get your book!"
>
> The girl with the green tatoo said "What are you doing?"

I am trying to get the word "said" from the sentence above.

Here's what I have so far :

```
def between(value, a, b):
    # Find and validate before-part.
    pos_a = value.find(a)
    if pos_a == -1: return ""
    # Find and validate after part.
    pos_b = value.rfind(b)
    if pos_b == -1: return ""
    # Return middle part.
    adjusted_pos_a = pos_a + len(a)
    if adjusted_pos_a >= pos_b: return ""
    return value[adjusted_pos_a:pos_b]

print(between(test, [0], '"'))
```

I use the code above, and it gave me

> TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: You want to get the word _said_ according to what criteria? You want to get the last word before a quoted section?

Comment: `a` is a list so the string `test` will never be able to find it

Comment: Yes. I want get the word _said_ before the quoted. but in my case, the word _said_ is not in the same position. @khelwood

Comment: you need the word alone or the position of the word 'said'?

Comment: The exception message tells you all - you have a list where the code expects a string. You never said what `test` is. I ran your code, and I get a different error.

Comment: I just need to extract the word _said_ @SmashGuy

Comment: I don't understand what your aim is. If you know you just want the word `said`, why not just put `return "said"` ?

Comment: If you intend to find "said", then find it. Why are you looking for double quotes `"`?

Comment: Sorry. test is the input. I forgot to include it. But if u change the print section became print(between(test, 'a', '"')) it'll workd @Sнаđошƒаӽ

Comment: One example sentence is insufficient for a functional specification. What to do, if there are more words in between, which special characters like interpunctuation may be ignored.....

Comment: Not working mate @khelwood

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what is being asked".

Comment: If I had the power, I would rather delete it. No offence to the OP - you are welcome to ask questions on SO, but only by following the _rules_, please.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Closing it is a step towards deleting it.

Comment: @khelwood hmm, but how? Any pointers, possibly some link that describes the steps? Maybe I forgot, or didn't ever know it. It would definitely be better to know the steps specifically :P

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ - At 10k rep, you get the ability to vote to delete questions that are already closed (where appropriate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone have explained your error message, i would suggest a different method.

you can go with list comprehension for that.

```
def return_word(sentence, word):
    if word in sentence.split():
        return [i for i in sentence.split() if i == word][0]
    else:
        return ''
print(return_word('sample sentence', 'sentence'))
```

This code will get what you need. Though your requirement doesn't seem clear i hope you have something in background of this.

Cheers!

Comment: What if `a` doesn't have the 'said' in it? Since the OP is _trying to find_ 'said' in the test string, I am guessing there will be such cases too where the word 'said' isn't simply there in the sentence.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ is it okay now?

Comment: @SyafiqurRahman Please elaborate your requirement next time as you will get what you need soon.

Comment: @SmashGuy sorry but no. My point was that the question itself is very poorly specified. So what sense can the answers to a question that doesn't make sense in the first place make? None, right? Hope you understand why I said "no" ;-)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ i get your point. But I prefer to answer him as i understood what he is intended to ask. Though it doesn't make much sense for us, it might be a bigger part for his program. Relax man!

Comment: Sorry guys. I was so frustated. My apologies. I just want to get the word before the quote, but my word is terrible. @SmashGuy

Comment: It's ok @SyafiqurRahman. You will learn things gradually. Welcome to the world of programming!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the word used before the quoted sentence, you could split using the `"` and then split using the space `' '` as in the following example:

```
test = 'That pretty lady said "Get your book!"'
test.split('"')[0].split(' ')[-2]
```

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that are poorly specified. If the question doesn't make sense, what sense can the answers to it make?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to create a problem. I just answered based on the comment "You want to get the last word before a quoted section?", to which he replied yes. I would have left it as a comment but I haven't yet unlocked this "feature"

Answer (score 0):

I renamed your between to word_before

```
def word_before(text, char_after):
    return text.split(char_after, maxsplit=1)[0].split(" ")[-2]
```

Using it with your test strings:

```
>>> tests = [
...     'He said "I am his father."',
...     'That pretty lady said "Get your book!"',
...     'The girl with the green tatoo said "What are you doing?"',
... ]
>>>
>>> for text in tests: print(word_before(text, '"'))
...
said
said
said
```

How does it work? 
The first split will split you string in half at your given character then stop searching(that's why we use maxsplit=1). 
The second split will split the text into words (every space), we take the second last item because the last one is actually just an empty string `''`.
We then return this result.

If you want to further improve upon this you can add a `try-except`-block checking for IndexError, this would indicate that it didn't find any match.

For instance you could do something along these lines

```
def word_before(text, char_after):
    parts = text.split(char_after, maxsplit=1)
    if len(parts) <= 1:
        return ''  # No match

    try:
        match = parts[0].split(" ")[-2]
    except IndexError:
        return '' # No word before

    return match
```

Which would give following result on a mismatch

```
>>> word_before("No quote here", '"')
''
```